# how to do load test to find the maximum vusers that the application can handle?

Tags: jmeter, loadrunner

We have a PHP application to do load test. The application team wants to know that, up to how many users that the application can be capable to withstand without any crashes.

How to do the load test on the same.. Please help us.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Its a boardroom question, application system capacity depends upon the application design and server where application is hosted.   Ultimately this depends the purpose of application (public or private) and customer requirements (number of users).
You can find notes on  test strategy for loading application in MSDN website **[Real-World Load Testing Tips to Avoid Bottlenecks When Your Web App Goes Live](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188783.aspx#S4)**. 
 My suggestion is application should able to manage atleast 10% maximum expected user simultaneously  (**till its popular... !!!!**).

Answer (score 2):

Try record and run Jmeter.
Use Summary Report, Summary Error Report and View Results Tree to see your server's health.
Keep adding thread counts till you realized all your thread group assertion starts failing.

My application includes complex data retrieval from RDC using XML. If error are less than 2% total test, i consider it as healthy. My app can handle 50 threads consecutively easily. Try yours. good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can identify the number of actual users experimentally. 
At the first, make virtual users behavior like real user. Follow [this](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/115022-how-to-make-jmeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) link to get it.

Then increase number of users and observe application behavior. To scedule increasing number of users, you can use [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)